# Posting JSON in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've got a fairly easy question today. I have an app that needs to send a simple JSON array to a remote server in the form of 2D GPS coordinates. The app will use the CoreLocation framework in order to generate these coordinates. For now, I want to hard code some sample coordinates to get the JSON right. However, I cannot seem to form the JSON correctly within the ObjC code.

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:myserver/handler/index"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *jsonString = @"{"
@"  \"geo\": {"
@"    \"lat\": \"37.78\","
@"    \"lon\": \"-122.40";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
(void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Here is what the server is expecting (but not receiving):

```
{
"geo": {
    "lat": "37.78",
    "lon": "-122.40"
}
```

I'm sure it's a simple JSON formatting issue or otherwise numskull move on my part.

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be missing some curly brackets there in your json strings

Comment: Also, why that `jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`?

Comment: You could also just store your data in an array and then let `NSJSONSerialization` do the work for you.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? It's a reasonable question and at least there is an attempt at solving it.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Not sure what you mean? Is that an extra step?

Comment: @Abizem - How would you do that?

Comment: Quick Update - I've changed the code to this and still no dice: NSString *jsonString = @"{"
    @"  \"geo\": {"
    @"    \"lat\": \"37.78\","
    @"    \"lon\": \"-122.40"
    @"}";

Comment: @ebeniezer I mean, why is that line there? `jsonString` is already an NSString. You convert it to `NSData` and then you convert that `NSData` back to the very same `NSString` - why?

Comment: You're missing two closing `}` characters.  But you should not generate variable JSON this way, but should construct the appropriate NSDictionaries and NSArrays and "serialize" them into the JSON.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Presumably that's so he can log that string.

Comment: @HotLicks But `jsonString` is existent from the beginnings: `NSString *jsonString = @"{" @"  \"geo\": {"` etc.

Comment: @H2CO3 - He wanted to make sure it didn't get garbled in the translation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing this the hard way. Create an `NSDictionary` then convert that to the desired JSON data:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"geo" : @{ @"lat" : @"37.78", @"lon" : @"-122.40" } };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonData) {
    // process the data
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to serialize the data %@: %@", dictionary, error);
}
```

No need for the string at all.

Edit: If your real data is an array of objects then create an array of dictionaries or whatever structure you need. The rest is the same.

Answer (score -4):

You are missing a semicolon. Check below :

```
   {
geo =     {
    "-122.40" = lon;
    "37.78" = lat;
};
```

}

Ideally you would need to do this:

```
NSDictionary *positionDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"lat",@"37.78",@"lon",@"-122.40", nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:positionDictionary, @"geo", nil];
```

And then pass the jsonDict.

Comment: That's not how json is formatted, OP had it right, less the missing end braces.

Comment: Barryjones - Doesn't seem to want to work, thanks for the try!

Comment: @ebeniezer - this is not wrong, merely incomplete. Add another line: 'NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:nil]; Then pass JSONData.