# JSON POST request for Rails 4.0 app gives response code 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been having an issue with posting JSON requests to my Rails 4.0 app for the purpose of logging in.  I set up a very minimal log-in-log-out session controller so that I can understand how Rails can accept JSON requests, instead of fiddling with a richer library such as devise.  After hours of confusion and mixing and matching methods on both the client end and the server end, I believe the problem lies in my lack of understanding on how Rails parses JSON requests that arrive as strings and can be handled through Rails.  The sessions controller used for logging in and out is found below:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: params}
  end

  def new    
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

The activity on Rails shows the following when receiving the JSON request:

```
Started POST "/login/" for ::1 at 2015-07-17 21:47:49 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"{session:{email: 'user@example.com',password: 'aaaaaa', remember_me: 1}}"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

I tried many variations from putting quotes around both the key and associated values, putting quotes around only the keys, only the values, but ultimately, the JSON request would be picked up as a string with this unparsed format: "{session......}" or "session:{...}" instead of a parsed hash like

```
"session"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}
```

For reference, the message I get from a successful login from a browser shows the following:

```
Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2015-07-18 13:28:45 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AmuA2AJUYmnnexUUTCYsLhyNTxUI1t4sf7rbW9WcD7/Amt33DMAR8QHQM5U9RT0oEd0Y5jN564r7bpVf9PjxAg==", "session"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (16.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "user@example.com"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 313ms (ActiveRecord: 17.4ms)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

ADDENDUM:

Below is the code for the view for logging in:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Login') %>
<h1>Log in</h1>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
        <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, class:'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :remember_me, class: 'checkbox inline' do%>
                <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
            <%= f.text_area :buh, class:'form-control' %>
            <% end %>


            <%= f.submit 'Log in', class:'btn btn-primary'%>

            <p>New user? <%= link_to 'Sign up now!', signup_path %></p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Objective C code used to post the http request:

```
- (IBAction)loginPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;

//payload below
    NSString *cookie = [self CSRFTokenFromURL:@"http://localhost:3000/login"];

    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"'session':{'email': '%@','password': '%@', 'remember_me': '1' }",username.text,password.text];
    NSLog(@"Postdata: %@",post);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:3000/login/"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRF-Token"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", [response statusCode]);

    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error:&error];
        success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

        if (success == 1) {
            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
        } else {
            NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
            [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I'm doing this to educate myself on the basic ways in which Rails works with JSON httprequests and not so much in using RESTKit, AFNetworking, Devise or the variety of other libraries out there for handling creation of log in sessions, between Objective C and Rails, which is why I withheld the Objective C, as I imagine it would make the original request messier than necessary.

Comment: If the request contains the header `Content-Type: application/json`, then the params should be parsed automatically for you. It may be useful to see the frontend code that's making the request (any HTML and JavaScript).

Comment: It seems that your params are string. How do you create a request?

Comment: james246: I don't have any HTML or JS for the request, although I have added the code for the view for the form to be submitted using a browser, which I've now included in my original post as well as the Objective C used to build and post the request.

Comment: BroiSatse: I create it either through posting on a form, which I've just added or via JSON requests generated by Objective C.

Comment: Your objectve C code is on fault here. Have a look at this question to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698387/posting-json-in-objective-c

Comment: james246: I just changed the `Content-Type` to `application/json` and that helped tremendously.
BroiSatse: thank you for that link. I found another thread using dictionaries/hashes to build a JSON request and that one failed me miserably.  I'm almost out of the woods!

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer to your parameters, you'll see they are in incorrect format, I would recommend you to test it with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"session":{"email":"user@example.com", "password":"yourpass", "remember_me":"0"}' http://localhost:3000/login
```

Comment: Rustam: thank you. I tried the code you gave and as you predicted, the test failed and using another of the formats that I've been working with, it passed with the hash parsed as I'd like it.  The code is as follows:
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"session":{"email":"user@example.com", "password":"yourpass", "remember_me":"0"}}' http://localhost:3000/login`